# What should I do to access camera in a UWP application using MediaCapture?

Tags: c#, uwp, camera, media

I try to access camera in a UWP application but I have an error:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' in mscorlib.ni.dll
WinRT information: Access is denied.

The app was denied access to the camera
The thread 0x2c9c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[3352] CameraGetPreviewFrame.exe' has exited with code 1 (0x1).
```

Here is my code:

```
if (cameraDevice == null)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("No camera device found!");
    return;
}

// Create MediaCapture and its settings
_mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();

// Register for a notification when something goes wrong
_mediaCapture.Failed += MediaCapture_Failed;

var settings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings { VideoDeviceId = cameraDevice.Id };

// Initialize MediaCapture
try
{
    await _mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(settings);
    _isInitialized = true;
}
catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("The app was denied access to the camera");
}
```

Could you explain to me why does the exception occur and how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should **set Microphone and Webcam Capabilities** for your project. To do it you can follow the steps below

1. Open **Package.appxmanifest**
2. Go to **Capabilities Tab**
3. Check **Microphone** and **Webcam**